# Recognize a handwritten word from a Spanish town

Tags: palaeography, spain

I am working on the investigation with old documentation, to see if you can help me to recognize this town in Spain, it could be in Castilla La Mancha, although I do not know for sure.

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: There is a place INGUIO in the Indies, is that any help?

Comment: Muchas gracias, tengo la certeza de que es en España. Pero muchas gracias.

Answer (score 6):

I think it reads *Enguid<sup>s</sup>*

Note that the last letter (an S) is a superior letter. I think it is an abbreviation of the name of the town.

So it could be [Enguídanos](https://www.google.com/maps/place/16372+Engu%C3%ADdanos,+Cuenca/@39.6742233,-1.6115751,16z/), a town about 23km from *Graja de Iniesta*.

Answer (score 4):

I think it reads:

> natural de *la Trajo de Imeita* [wrong]
>
> natural de *la Graja de Iniesta*
> término municipal de *id* [idéntico]
> provincia de *Quenca*

(thanks @Javi García and @Trebia Project for clarifying) but since that is not what was asked for I think the other location referenced does not start with a G because there are enough captial Gs that look different. I don't think it is an I either because if you look at "Graja de Iniesta" that would rule out an I. I rather think it is either an J or an Y. I think the third letter is rather a g than a y because there are a lot of examples of "ya" in which the y is thinner. n and u look quite similar, most probably the rounder one is the u and the edgier one is the n. What is puzzling is that in two occurrences the second letter seems to be a u and the fourth one a n while in two other occurrences this seem to be reversed. Because of that I also wouldn't rule out the possibility that both are u's.

That would mean that it is either "J/Yugnio/a" or "J/Yuguio/a".

Comment: En la línea que indicas pone "Granja de Iniesta", pero esa no es la que tengo dudas. Es en la frase "Sebastian Álvarez García de ................ ya difunto" y "María García de ............ ya difunta".

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is not fully correct, the very first place is "[Graja de Iniesta](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graja_de_Iniesta)" and not "GraNja". Granja means farm in Spanish and Graja is a bird species, that's why it might look more sensible to assume a place will be named "Graja". In order to determine better the names of localities I usually double check the names [here](https://www.mjusticia.gob.es/BUSCADIR/ServletControlador?apartado=buscadorGeneral&tipo=RC).

For the second location it is written that way when the locality if nearby the location of the register. Which is the registry source of this birth register? (based on that will be a location close to that register, or even a neighbourhood). Written is quite cryptic...

Comment: Es un certificado de nacimiento, he tratado de buscar todos los pueblos del registro pero no veo nada parecido. Inicialmente puse solo las dos palabras que pedía ayuda para reconocer, pero me pidieron que subiera más imágenes.

Comment: Pero de qué localidad es el certificado?

Comment: En principio es de Cuenca

Comment: Cuenca ciudad o provincia? Busco el municipio exacto que emitió esa partida

Comment: Lo que suelo hacer es cuando hay nombres como esos que la grafia no deja mirar, pido otro partida para comparar o me voy a la web del ministerio donde están todos los pueblos de la pronvincia y busco el que se parezca (https://www.mjusticia.gob.es/BUSCADIR/ServletControlador?lang=&apartado=buscadorMunicipios&URL_ORIGEN=&origen=G&tipo=RC&provincia=16), no he visto ninguno. El posible probelma es que el municipio cambiara de nombre, entonces es más dificil

Comment: Es de la provincia de Cuenta, pero no lo puedo asegurar. No es un problema de la copia, más bien de escritura, no obstante, muchas gracias ;)

Comment: @JaviGarcía la estrategia es empezar desde la localidad de donde es la partida de nacimiento y mirar en un mapa municipios con grafia parecida, he probado eso desde Cuenca ciudad y Graja. Por eso es importante saber de dónde exactamente es la partida